Different logo on computer / mobile screen sizes on Big Cartel
I have a square logo that looks good on a computer screen but is very small on mobile screens. I have a narrow, easier to read logo to put on the mobile screen but don't know how to do this in the CSS section on Big Cartel. Can anyone post the needed code?
I have messed with the code in the CSS editor and ended up having to reinstall the theme cuz I messed the whole site up.

It would be more appropriate to direct your question to the developer of the theme you are using.

What's the site's URL?

I tried contacting the developer and they are unable to provide coding help. The URL is rangerstation.bigcartel.com
